# Links inside of div or span not working?

Tags: html, css

I have a simple div with three images in it and Im trying to make all three images separate html links

Am I missing something? This seems too easy, but it surely doesn't work:

```
<div><a href="#"><img src="img/dboarddown.png"></a><img src="img/ranking.png"><img src="img/analytics.png"></div>
```

span doesnt work either....I dont get the pointer and nothing is click-able.

Comment: you missed the close tag of image.

Comment: Your img tag needs to be closed, eg <img src="img/dboarddown.png" />

Comment: @flauntster IMG tags are self-closing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you only got one link:

```
<div>
    <a href="#"><img src="img/dboarddown.png"></a>
    <img src="img/ranking.png">
    <img src="img/analytics.png">
</div>
```

replace to:

```
<div>
    <a href="#"><img src="img/dboarddown.png" alt="" /></a>
    <a href="http://stackoverflow.com"><img src="img/ranking.png" alt="" /></a>
    <a href="http://google.com"><img src="img/analytics.png" alt="" /></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

this should work just fine

```
<div>
 <a href="#link1">
  <img src="img/dboarddown.png"/>
 </a>
 <a href="#link2">
  <img src="img/ranking.png"/>
 </a>
 <a href="#link3">
  <img src="img/analytics.png"/>
 </a>
</div>
```

Comment: What is it doing, @TechnoCripple?  is the url being updated with the #linkX anchor in the browser?  is it possible theres another element overlaying above this div, blocking it from hover/click events?

Comment: Found the issue...left a -1 z index in the upper div...working fine now...Thanks for the help...thought I was going crazy..:)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div><a href="#"><img src="img/dboarddown.png"/></a>
    <a href="#"> <img src="img/ranking.png"/></a>
    <a href="#"><img src="img/analytics.png"/></a></div>
```

Last two images are not wrapped in to  tag and don't forget to close img tag.

Comment: @flauntster Not closing your image tags is valid according to the HTML5 spec.

Comment: @oGeez what about HTML5 img tags and the alt attribute?

Comment: Answer is about what to do to get it working. Not about HTML5 or attribute required to get totaly valid code.